# send a numeric value to a web-service with JSON framework

Tags: web-services, json, ios

to send a String i put that :

```
[request setPostValue:choixCommerce forKey:@"ssiphone_commerce"];//choixCommerce is a NSString
```

it's ok, and for numeric value i try to put that :

```
[request setPostValue:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];//longitude is NSInteger type
```

but i got this error :

```
 incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setPostValue:forKey:'
```

how should i do to send a numeric value please ? thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an NSNumber and not an NSInteger :

```
[request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your clarification, i would just to ask if this will be the same work if my longitude type is float and not NSInteger or it will be another code to put ? thx